# how to delete project on tfs2012 from vs2010 ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm trying to delete a project on my tfs 2012 but i got this error

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE>TFSDeleteproject /q /f
orce /collection:https://******.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/ MvcMusi
cStore
TF200040: You cannot delete a team project with your version of Team Explorer. C
ontact your system administrator to determine how to upgrade your Team Explorer
client to the version compatible with Team Foundation Server.

I create MvcMusic Store Project with vs2011 but now i have vs2010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download Team Explorer Everywhere for Team Foundation and from your console you able execute your commands download http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661 (require java runtime).

Command line guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg413282(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are running the `TFSDeleteProject` utility from the Visual Studio 2010 folder. Its likely that you have more than one version of Team Explorer installed, each of them going into their own installation path.

The 2010 and 2012 version of TFS Server and Team Explorer are largely cross-compatible, but there are some operations that you cannot do without the correct version. Deleting a project is one of these things; you have to use a 2012 version Team Client if you want to delete projects from the 2012 version of the server.

There are three ways you can delete projects from a TFS 2012 system. The first is to install the Team Explorer client from the TFS 2012 install onto a machine. (I have Team Explorer installed on the server itself, for example). Once installed, the client tools will be found at:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE`

Alternatively, as you discovered, you can install the [Team Anywhere](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661) client, which apparently also lets you delete projects.

Lastly, if you have access to the TFS Server Admin console, you have the ability to delete team projects from there.

Comment: if for some reason you're still running a 32-bit OS, drop the "(x86)" part, obviously.

Comment: i dont have folder vs11.0, because i have vs2010, and got a update for use with tfs 2012 (Visual Studio 2010 SP1 Team Foundation Server 2012 Compatibility GDR).

Comment: There are some things that you cannot do with VS2010's Team Explorer client when connected to a TFS 2012 server. You can either install Team Explorer 2012 on your machine, or use the Admin console on the server.

Comment: Thanks , i just install Team Explorer Everywhere for Team Foundation and by console i able to delete :) http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30661 (require java runtime). Thanks for your help.If you want to put your comment in the response area to vote.